# Default yeoman angular app with wiredep, concat, and cdnify -- how is anything actually cdnify'd?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, cdn, yeoman

I've got an angular project that I started up with default yeoman settings.

Looking through how the build process works, I can't imagine how any of my bower dependencies are automatically cdnifyed and what the point of the cdnify task are.

First of all, yeoman sets everything up with wiredep, which wires in my bower dependencies into a spot into index.html. It looks like:

```
<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Looking at my Gruntfile from Yeoman, it appears that

1. Wiredep forces all bower dependencies into this block
2. The whole block is then compiled into a vendor.js

and finally

1. cdnify runs, identifying any free script tags and attempting to replace with cdn'd versions.

This seems rather silly to me. But before I go into hacking up my Gruntfile, I wanted to try to make sure that my understanding is correct.

I can't simply copy-paste easily cdnify'd dependencies outside of this block, because wiredep is just going to put them back in. If I did that index.html would include jquery twice, for example. Once in vendor.js and second from a cdn.

If I want to use cdnify, then I need to get away from wiredep, and manually decide which dependencies should be cdnify'd and which shouldn't.

It seems yeoman would be smarter than this, and I wanted to make sure I'm not the dumb one here. Is it true that this setup is somewhat contradictory/redundant? Am I missing something?

**update** it appears that placing scripts outside of this block causes wiredep not to place them in the bower block. I can't find anywhere that says this is documented behavior, however.

Comment: not an answer, but my conclusion from this question would be: yeoman creates project templates that vary wildly in quality. don't trust it any farther than you can throw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the bottom of the grunt file which has registered tasks and remove things like CDNify from a task like grunt build. Grunt will then skip that step next time.